# How to process after all option have been chosen and start new process on a console menu based application

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and developing application. This is for a class project

I am writing a C# based console application for a food truck. I have built the main menu with several submenus for the end user to choose what they want to order. I am stuck at the end when the end-user has made their choices, and I want the application to process their choices and restart the process for another customer to place an order.

I have not tried anything as I know little about C#. I taught myself the C# during the class as I did not want to use java and wanted to expand my knowledge of a different programming language.

Below are some screenshots of what I have.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGc0L.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnGzu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Yn5.png)

What I am trying to achieve is when the customer arrows down to "Done" it processes the choices made in the menus, then restarts fresh to allow another customer to place an order.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post actual code not screen shots to enable use to best assist you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just stick everything in a class, and recreate the class during each cycle

```
public class MainClass {
    public void Run() {
        while (true)
        {
            var myFoo = new Foo(); //each end of cycle we recreate myFoo from scratch, starting a clean run
            myFoo.RunProcessToCompletion();
        }
    }
}
public class Foo
{
    private string field1 = ""; //your class can have fields to remember info while processing
    private string field2 = "";
    public void RunProcessToCompletion() { 
        //do all your interactions here
    }
}
```

The above is just a very basic sample, but by running it like that, you do whatever you want in your Foo class, and then trust that it'll all be reset at the next cycle

If you want more specific help, then include some of your actual code